# Photoshop CS6: whats the name of this tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is the name of the tool indicated by arrow on photo in Adobe Photoshop CS6, and how can I find it from my tools bar?

[image: Adobe Photoshop CS6 Toolbar]

Comment: This is the place for the **Eraser Tool**, but this is not an Adobe tool icon

Comment: Looks exactly like the Adobe Eraser Tool to me - certainly the one in CC2018 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC7RZ.png idk if it used to look much different in CS6, been too long since I saw it.

Comment: It's the eraser tool.  If you can't find it, it's probably hiding under another tool. Click and hold a tool, to see the tools hidden under it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It should be an eraser tool though its icon looks somehow different from my CS6

Comment: @MahadiMatsawily - CS6 was released in 2012. The example you posted is from one of the CC versions of which there have been around 22 updates since version CS6. The design of the icons has changed a bit, but it's still the exact same tool.

Answer (score 0):

Eraser tool most likely. In my Photoshop (also CS6), when i position the mouse over one of those tools, and keep it there for 2-3 seconds, a popup shows up with the actual name of the tool I am looking at. Try it.